# Tailwind CSS Fixed NavBar

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a `Fixed Navigation Bar` in `Tailwind CSS` and sticky scroll main page, but no matter what I try, I can't make it work...

Here is what I achieved:

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
<!-- NavBar -->
<header class="fixed bg-blue-600 shadow-md  z-50 w-full px-5 py-2 flex justify-between items-center">
    <router-link to="/" class="text-2xl text-white">My App</router-link>
    <div>
        <router-link to="/login" class="text-white hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 rounded py-1">Login</router-link>
        <router-link to="/register" class="text-white hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 rounded py-1">Register</router-link>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="flex">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside class="fixed bg-white h-screen py-5 shadow">
        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
            <router-link to="/" class="hover:bg-gray-400 px-12 py-2 rounded">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="">Dashboard</span>    
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- Main Page -->
    <main class="bg-gray-200  flex-1">
        <transition name="slide-fade">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 205):

If someone is still looking for this, here the solution using the rights tailwind classes.

my layout look like this:

```
<div>
   <header class="sticky top-0 z-50"></header>
   <main class=relative></main>
   <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly in Chrome but is not "sticky" in Safari

Comment: Just tested in Safari, works fine (aka is sticky) for me.

Comment: Also works for me in Safari as well as Firefox.

Comment: This is not working in 2022. I am applying it to <nav> and it is just not working. Funny enough 6this is the same on Tailwind docs. Here is what I am doing:

<nav className="sticky top-0 flex w-full items-center justify-between py-6">

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working for me. 
That's what I did:

<header className="sticky top-0 z-50">
  <div className="relative">
    <nav>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

Answer (score 14):

Here is the solution by using only Flex box.

CodeSandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/y7g7g?file=/index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Sticky-header-and-footer-with-tailwind</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
      <header class="py-5 bg-gray-700 text-white text-center">
        Sticky Header and Footer with Tailwind
      </header>
      <main class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto p-5">
        What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
        and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
        dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
        not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
      </main>
      <footer class="py-5 bg-gray-700 text-center text-white">
        Tailwind is Awesome 
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is scrolling problems using this approach on iphone, chrome. There appears to be 2 different scrolls and not working properly when you go all the way down.

Answer (score 12):

Using 'Fixed NavBar' in Tailwind.
Here is the template code for you to get started:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tailwind Starter Template - Fixed Header : Tailwind Toolbox</title>
    <meta name="author" content="name">
    <meta name="description" content="description here">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Replace with your tailwind.css once created-->
    <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Totally optional :) -->
    
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-400 font-sans leading-normal tracking-normal">

    <!--Nav-->
    <nav class="bg-gray-800 p-2 mt-0 fixed w-full z-10 top-0">
        <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center">
            <div class="flex w-full md:w-1/2 justify-center md:justify-start text-white font-extrabold">
                <a class="text-white no-underline hover:text-white hover:no-underline" href="#">
                    <span class="text-2xl pl-2"><i class="em em-grinning"></i> Brand McBrandface</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex w-full pt-2 content-center justify-between md:w-1/2 md:justify-end">
                <ul class="list-reset flex justify-between flex-1 md:flex-none items-center">
                  <li class="mr-3">
                    <a class="inline-block py-2 px-4 text-white no-underline" href="#">Active</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="mr-3">
                    <a class="inline-block text-gray-600 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="mr-3">
                    <a class="inline-block text-gray-600 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                    <li class="mr-3">
                    <a class="inline-block text-gray-600 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <!--Container-->
    <div class="container shadow-lg mx-auto bg-white mt-24 md:mt-16 h-screen">
        
    <p>Here you Go!</p>
        
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another simple combination you can try.

```
<nav class="w-full fixed top-0 z-50">

  <!--Your content inside navbar -->
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>

</nav>
```

According to the given source code, it should be like this.

```
<div>
   <header class="fixed top-0 z-50"></header>
   <main class=relative></main>
   <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Flex in Tailwind Navbar

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="bg-gray-100 fixed inset-x-0">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4">
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div class="flex space-x-4">
                <!-- logo -->
                 <div> <a href="#" class="flex items-center py-5 px-2 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900"> <i class='bx bxl-medium-old mr-1 text-xl mb-1 text-blue-400'></i> 
        <span class="font-bold">Moto Dev</span> </a> </div> <!-- primary nav -->
                <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1"> <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900">Home</a> <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900">Contact</a> <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900">Pricing</a> <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900">Features</a> </div>
            </div> <!-- secondary nav -->
            <div class="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1"> <a href="" class="py-5 px-3">Login</a> <a href="" class="py-2 px-3 bg-yellow-400 text-white hover:bg-yellow-300 text-sm hover:text-yellow-800 rounded transition duration-300">Signup</a> </div> <!-- mobile button goes here -->
            <div class="md:hidden flex items-center"> <button class="mobile-menu-button focus:outline-none"> <i class='bx bx-menu text-3xl mt-1'></i> </button> </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- mobile menu -->
         <div class="mobile-menu hidden md:hidden"> <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200">Home</a> <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200">Contact</a> <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200">Pricing</a> 
    <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-4 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200">Features</a> </div>
       </nav>
<!-- content goes here -->
     <div class="py-32 bg-red-500 h-screen p-3"> </div>
```

Or Visit [Tailwind CSS Navbar](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/tailwind-css-fixed-navbar-menu-button-71209833)